# How to solve Django server issue

Tags: django

(base) osx@localhost Api_test % python manage.py runserver

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 16, 2020 - 05:36:03
Django version 3.0.8, using settings 'Api_test.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Error: That port is already in use.
```

(base) osx@localhost Api_test %

Answer (score 1):

if you're using mac try any of the following:

```
lsof -n -i4TCP:8000 
sudo lsof -i tcp:8000 
npx kill-port 8000
```

if you are using linux:

```
sudo fuser -k 8000/tcp
```

Comment: Thanks @Vishal very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this problem for a while now and I always use the code below:

```
fuser -k 8000/tcp
```

I'm on Ubuntu and I have this issue...even tried VSCode's and Pycharm's terminals but got no answer then tried above code and it worked for me.